# In Nx + Angular monorepo architecture, where should I put testing helpers that are specific to just one library?

Tags: angular, architecture, nrwl-nx, micro-frontend

For context, we have an Angular + Nx monorepo with just one main `app` currently, but we plan to split it to a few separate microfrontends soon.

We currently have just one main module, `util-models`, that contains *all* the interfaces describing *all* the API interactions, and also *all* the stubs we use in tests to mock data.

Now let's say I have a library `my-feature` that contains some feature that I'll want to build and deploy (as a lazily-loaded route or as a part of the main bundle). This library already depends on `util-models`, because it deals with some standardized data, but we also have there a separate `my-model.model.ts` file that only describes interfaces specific to this one feature.

---

Some visual representation:

```
\my-feature
  \lib
    - my-models.model.ts
    - my-component.component.ts
    - my-component.component.spec.ts

\util-models
  \lib
    - shared-model.model.ts
    \test
      - shared-model.stub.ts
```

---

So the question is, where should I put my `my-models.stub.ts` file that contains all of the library-specific stubs?

1. The first obvious answer would seem to be "put your library-specific code in the library". But does that mean that all of my libraries should actually aim to have a separate `test` directory for all stubs or test utils that are specific to them? Does that apply to models too (which aren't even compilable code, just interfaces)? Doesn't that reduce the discoverability of these tools that are supposed to assist devs, in case some other library in the future was also actually dealing with the same data structures?

Also, will this code get automatically dropped from the prod build alongside the regular `.spec.ts` files? Is it enough to just not import it in the `module`?

2. Another option would be putting it in the already existing `util-models` library, which `my-feature` will probably keep depending on, but obviously I'm worried that just makes it less separated in the long run. On the other hand, if this is just testing code that will never go to production anyway, then maybe that's actually fine, or even desirable for some reason?

---

I'm mostly interested in how both options would potentially affect things like build/test build times, tree shaking, lazy loading, and migration to microfrontends. I'd appreciate any tips!

Comment: Such a good question!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I haven't found any official document that would clear this up, but after spending more time with Nx, and especially after learning more about DDD (Domain Driven Development), I grew more of an *intuition*.

My current intuition is that "discoverability" of code between libraries that are actually unrelated is not a feature, it's a problem. All code should belong to its own specific domain, not get centralized in some large generic library - it doesn't matter if it's only interfaces or testing code.

Each "shared" library, if we allow it to exist in our dependency tree, has to have a purpose specific to at most one domain.

Therefore I now feel confident with the following decisions:

1. We should aim to disband the central `util-models` library. Models describing API responses all can be assigned to more specific domains.
2. If we want to reuse models between feature libraries, because we are certain they actually *do* belong to the same business domain, then we will create a separate util library only for sharing **those specific models for this specific domain**.
3. As logically follows, we should start including separate `test` directories in any libraries that own models, in order to have model stubs ready when we want to test our components/services/etc. in that library.

Comment: @AndrewAllen Let me reiterate what I pointed in my answer as a TL;DR: Having one central "shared" lib is a very bad idea. Possibly in this example small repo there is only one actual domain, and so perhaps only one "shared" lib needs to exist. But after a glance at its contents, I don't think so. Please don't recommend centralized shared libraries as example solution to devs who aren't 100% sure what they're doing and why.

Comment: @AndrewAllen Sure, it would, but in this repo there's only one "domain" - `web` - so it's not a very good example for people who aren't confident with Nx/DDD yet (who are most likely to stumble upon this SO thread : ))

Comment: @AndrewAllen Do you mind explaining why is that a problem? Would you prefer to not see this answer at all, or for me to not mention DDD despite it being very relevant to my problem-solving train of thoughts? Linking Nx to DDD is not some random unfounded idea, and many other people have adopted it too - see e.g. https://levelup.gitconnected.com/moduliths-in-angular-with-nx-b8b0076794fb

Comment: I added a link that I thought was helpful, addressed the one domain issue question, and pointed out your question doesn't mention multiple domains anyway so seems a harsh criticism. I deleted my comments because I don't want to engage further. Please stop @ing me